# DataStore in flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am having problems in my program... Please advice me of what is right

this is the error code of my prog

```
mx.data::Conflict {
  cause = mx.data.messages::DataMessage {
    body = [["lessonid"],
    {
      lessonid = 17
      lessonplanid = 1
      status = "active"
      studentid = 4
    },
    valueObjects::Lessonplan {
      lessonid = 18
      lessonplanid = 1
      status = "active"
      studentid = 4
    }]
    clientId = null
    correlationId = ""
    destination = "lessonplanRPCDataManager"
    headers = {
      newReferencedIds = null
      prevReferencedIds = null
    }
    identity = {
      lessonplanid = 1
    }
    messageId = "28DEF63D-9002-787E-188A-67DFD27407F8"
    operation = 3
    timestamp = 0
    timeToLive = 0
  }
  causedByLocalCommit = false
  clientObject = valueObjects::Lessonplan {
    lessonid = 18
    lessonplanid = 1
    status = "active"
    studentid = 4
  }
  destination = "lessonplanRPCDataManager"
  errorID = 0
  message = "Local item has changes to properties that conflict with remote change."
  name = "Error"
  originalObject = {
    lessonid = 17
    lessonplanid = 1
    status = "active"
    studentid = 4
  }
  propertyNames = ["lessonid"]
  resolved = false
  serverObject = lessonplanid=1
  serverObjectDeleted = false
  serverObjectReferencedIds = {
  }
}
    at mx.data::DataStore/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::processConflict()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataStore.as:3428]
    at mx.data::ConcreteDataService/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::updateCache()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ConcreteDataService.as:5468]
    at mx.data::ConcreteDataService/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::updateCacheWithId()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ConcreteDataService.as:5316]
    at mx.data::DataList/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::processSequence()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataList.as:2582]
    at mx.data::DataList/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::processSequenceResult()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataList.as:2880]
    at mx.data::DataListRequestResponder/result()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataListRequestResponder.as:132]
    at mx.data::RPCDataServiceAdapter/sendResultEvent()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\RPCDataServiceAdapter.as:1508]
    at mx.data::RPCDataServiceAdapter/executeQueryResult()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\lcds_modeler101\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\RPCDataServiceAdapter.as:1444]
    at mx.collections::ItemResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ItemResponder.as:129]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncToken/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::applyResult()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncToken.as:239]
    at mx.rpc.events::ResultEvent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::callTokenResponders()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\events\ResultEvent.as:207]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractOperation.as:244]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:318]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:56]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:84]
    at NetConnectionMessageResponder/resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\NetConnectionChannel.as:547]
    at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\MessageResponder.as:235]
```

Comment: It is right to format code as code (use the {} button or indent 4 spaces): It will help getting your question answered. I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Flex documentation](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/data/DataStore.html#event%3aconflict) says, an error of type conflict is

> Dispatched when a conflict is detected
>   between either pending changes on this
>   client and changes submitted by
>   another client, or when changes
>   submitted by this client result detect
>   a conflict error at the remote
>   destination.

You will have to figure the solution out yourself (it is not something caused by Flex, but by the data you want to commit).

> Local item has changes to properties
>   that conflict with remote change.

sounds to me like you have some kind of verification failure, because

```
clientObject = valueObjects::Lessonplan {
    lessonid = 18
    lessonplanid = 1
    status = "active"
    studentid = 4   }
```

and

```
originalObject = {
    lessonid = 17
    lessonplanid = 1
    status = "active"
    studentid = 4
  }
```

are incompatible.  I suppose changing the lessionid is not allowed.

Comment: how can i allow it? when i restart the application I could see that the update was done correctly...but when i update it again it returns the same error..I am using PHP service by the way

Comment: Then it's probably because you need to merge ( http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/data/DataStore.html#merge() ) or refresh ( http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/data/DataStore.html#refresh() ) your local data before committing again.

Comment: I read your edited answer but I still can't understand what the upper part is saying. I disabled the datamanagement in that service..

Comment: SIR.....THANK YOU VERY MUCH..YOU ARE VERY IMBA..hahaha...YOU SAVED MY FUTURE CAREER!!!!tnx again

Comment: Sorry for asking: In my understanding, "IMBA" is an insult - did I do something to offend you, or did I actually answer your question?

Comment: hahaha..imba is just a term that we use here in our country. it's a praise actually. it means your very good.haha

Comment: Alright, thanx for clearing that up ;)  It is also an abbreviation for "imbalanced" - that's why I asked.